# Python Linux - pyinstaller isn't working with tkinter

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am trying to build a program in python for linux, that uses tkinter to make the GUI.
My program works when I open it through the terminal, but I want to make it an executable file, with an icon that you press and it opens it so I used `pyinstaller` to compile it.

however, when I try to double click the icon that was generated with the `pyinstaller` (in the folder `dist`) it doesn't open anything, and when I try to open it with the terminal I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FILE_NAME.py", line 291, in <module>
  File "lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1767, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "tcl_findLibrary"
Failed to execute script FILE_NAME
```

in line `291` I have this code:
`root = Tk()`

So I guess it is something the the `tkinter` that can't compile correctly.

any ideas what I can do?

Comment: `python2.7` or `python3.x`?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.6

Comment: best guess your using something that `pyinstaller` has difficulty converting to .exe or your app has some dependencies that you have in the .py version but not converted with the .exe

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I think it is the tkinter also because the error message. and, linux doesn't have .exe. I want to mention that in windows, `pyinstaller` converted it fime, just in linux it has problams. any idea how to fix it?

Comment: not sure but i would suggest reading this to see if you have a similar situation https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2015